# GObject and inheritance

Tags: inheritance, glib, gobject

I was doing some serious software on Glib. And I realized that there's some topics I don't really understand. IRC also didn't help so...

When we are doing inheritance, we can have two clases. The first one A inherits from GObject directly, B inherits from A. Then I came to this:

https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/chapter-gobject.html

```
static void
viewer_file_constructed (GObject *obj)
{
  /* update the object state depending on constructor properties */

  /* Always chain up to the parent constructed function to complete object
   * initialisation. */
  G_OBJECT_CLASS (viewer_file_parent_class)->constructed (obj);
}

static void
viewer_file_class_init (ViewerFileClass *klass)
{
  GObjectClass *object_class = G_OBJECT_CLASS (klass);

  object_class->constructed = viewer_file_constructed;
}
```

But when you have this kind of arrangement. The child class does this: object_class->constructed = viewer_file_constructed; in B overriding in fact the only memory address for constructed. So it means that G_OBJECT_CLASS (viewer_file_parent_class)->constructed (obj); will call B->constructed recursively. And it's not what we want.

Maybe I don't understand but I suppose that the memory structure in B is as this:

```
struct _B
{
  A parent_instance;

  /* instance members */
};
```

The internal representation should be something like:

```
[   Gobject struct memory ]
[                         ]
[   Gobject variables     ]
[   A struct memory       ]
[   A variables           ] 
[                         ]
[   B struct memory       ]
[   B variables           ]
```

So the GObject memory when casting in B is the shared by B and A classing. And all addresses are the same on the same i...

- G_OBJECT_CLASS (B)->constructed
- G_OBJECT_CLASS (A)->constructed

Is this correct?
So if I want to overwrite constructed... Do I have to save the pointer that had before and then overwrite it in init with mine? So I can call the original one after I do my processing?

The same applies with the properties. Because A defines it's properties by an enum, that can go from 0 to N.

So I suppose that B properties should start at N, not 0. Otherwise the properties of A are handled by B and maybe with different data structures, and names.

Check this:
https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-properties.html

```
enum
{
  PROP_FILENAME = 1,
  PROP_ZOOM_LEVEL,
  N_PROPERTIES
};
```

If both clases defines a property with index 1. There will be a problem there because glib doesn't know who should handle. I suppose the child class B will handle it but improperly because maybe B is waiting, say a PROP_DIRECTORY, but since the index is the same. Would glib able to send to right instance?

I can only thing it will work if on register glib will add some offset depending on hierarchy level. Can someone explain how this really works? I cannot find any document with desired technical detail.

Comment: It may be that the only way you'll get an answer is to look at the source...

Comment: GLib has been around for 20+ years. Its official documentation, like it, is stable and relatively slowly changing. You should presume such official docs know what they are talking about, instead of thinking you are the first person to suddenly identify such fundamental, totally breaking mistakes in it... In such cases, you should assume that you misunderstood and need to read more, not that the documentation is wrong. It's not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The internal representation should be something like:

Not quite. There’s a different between the `GObject` and `GObjectClass` structs. There’s one `GObject` struct instance per object instance, but only one `GObjectClass` instance for the entire class.

If you have a class `FooBar` deriving from `GObject`, the `FooBarClass` struct will look something like:

```
typedef struct
{
  GObjectClass parent_class;

  /* Virtual methods for FooBar instances: */
  void (*vfunc) (FooBar *self);
} FooBarClass;
```

There will be an instance of `FooBarClass` on the heap. Since it contains the entire `GObjectClass` struct as its `parent_class` member, that means it has its own `finalize`, `dispose`, `get_property`, etc. virtual method pointers.

Separately in the heap, there is an instance of `GObjectClass` for the GObject type. It contains another set of `finalize`, `dispose`, etc. virtual method pointers.

Since `FooBar` derives from `GObject`, `foo_bar_parent_class` will be set to point to the `GObjectClass` instance. This is what allows chaining up.

So if you want to implement the `constructed` virtual method and chain up (you *must* chain up `constructed`), just do as the [example code in the documentation you linked to does](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/chapter-gobject.html). It is correct.

---

> The same applies with the properties. Because A defines it's
>   properties by an enum, that can go from 0 to N.

Incorrect. When a property is registered with a class using `g_object_class_install_properties()`, the property indices are associated with the `GObjectClass` instance inside the class struct for that class. They are not associated with the stand-along `GObjectClass` struct for the GObject type. This is the same principle as above.

In other words, there is no global registry of property indices: it’s all done per-class. So you can (and should) start the indexing of properties from 1 for each of your classes. They will not conflict.

Note that, as stated in the documentation for [`g_object_class_install_properties()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-class-install-properties), the property index 0 is special, and must not be used. You must start your property indexing from 1.

---

As ptomato says, this is way beyond the level of detail appropriate for the documentation. You should read the source code.