# Merging structs in C

Tags: c, struct

Is there a way to combine two structs  `struct A` and `struct B` into a third `struct C` in a way that changes to either `struct A` or `struct B`, like adding a new field, are automagically reflected in `struct C`?

The motivation is that e.g. `struct A` comes from some library and `struct B` and is under my control and contains additional data not found in `struct A`; the purpose of `struct C` is to access the members of `struct A` and `struct B` via a uniform interface represented by `struct C`.

pseudocode:

```
struct A
{
    double a;
    double b;
    char    c;
};

struct B
{
    int d;
    float f;
};

struct C
{
    /* X does some magic struct-member declaration */
    X(A)
    X(B)
};

int main()
{
    C data;
    printf("%lf\n",data.a);
    printf("%d\n", data.d);
}
```

Comment: `struct C` could have members which *point to* `struct A` and `struct B`.

Comment: @WeatherVane but those pointers would have to have different names and I would e.g. have to access via C.pA->a and C.pB->d, so that doesn't provide a uniform access via C

Comment: I fail to see how they could have the same name.

Comment: Short answer: No, standard C has no such language facility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Microsoft Extensions to C that are supported by GCC, CLANG and MSVC.
Just add "-fms-extensions" option to the command line.
Those extension let one inlining members of the other structure with syntax:

```
struct C
{
    struct A;
    struct B;
};
```

Note that this is **not** a standard C.

Comment: I had tried that solution but got compiler errors because I didn't know about the extensions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to present an alternative solution to the problem, which is: you should not *want* to. The normal way is to just write:

```
struct C {
    struct A a;
    struct B b;
};
```

Then all members of both `A` and `B` are accessible from `C`, you just need to prefix them with `a.` or `b.`, like so:

```
struct C data;
printf("%lf\n",data.a.a);
printf("%d\n", data.b.d);
```

Note that what you say you want has some issues: since `struct B` contains a member named `d`, what would you expect to happen when the creator of the library that provides `struct A` decides to add a member named `d` as well?

Comment: It can be assumed that there will be no name clash between the members of `struct A`and `struct B`

Answer (score 2):

In short - base C does not have support for this without macro trickery or libraries

If you are open to the two - you could use something homegrown like this:

```
#define A_DEF double a,b; char c;
#define B_DEF int d; float f;

struct A
{
    A_DEF
};

struct B
{
    B_DEF
};

struct C
{
    A_DEF
    B_DEF
};
```

or a library like [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) which provides pretty sophisticated object-like functionality in C including a sort of faux-inheritance

Comment: `including a sort of faux-inheritance` I do not know, where does glib implement such inheritance, could you post some link?

Comment: @KamilCuk here's a decent SO Q on the matter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306127/gobject-and-inheritance

Comment: Thank you very much!